# Apply PERCENTILE.INC on aggregated results in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, percentile

I have the following dataset 'Table1'

| City | Brand | Year | Number_of_Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| London | A | 2019 | 387 |
| London | A | 2020 | 1566 |
| London | A | 2021 | 1409 |
| Manchester | A | 2019 | 353 |
| Manchester | A | 2020 | 679 |
| Manchester | A | 2021 | 1099 |
| Bristol | A | 2019 | 2999 |
| Bristol | A | 2020 | 2654 |
| Bristol | A | 2021 | 426 |
| York | A | 2019 | 214 |
| York | A | 2020 | 948 |
| York | A | 2021 | 1948 |
| Birmingham | A | 2019 | 452 |
| Birmingham | A | 2020 | 2465 |
| Birmingham | A | 2021 | 1856 |
| London | B | 2019 | 1829 |
| London | B | 2020 | 1236 |
| London | B | 2021 | 2960 |
| Manchester | B | 2019 | 2593 |
| Manchester | B | 2020 | 533 |
| Manchester | B | 2021 | 126 |
| Bristol | B | 2019 | 1588 |
| Bristol | B | 2020 | 2067 |
| Bristol | B | 2021 | 1823 |
| York | B | 2019 | 1667 |
| York | B | 2020 | 2931 |
| York | B | 2021 | 657 |
| Birmingham | B | 2019 | 2896 |
| Birmingham | B | 2020 | 421 |
| Birmingham | B | 2021 | 2488 |

I wish to apply PERCENTILE.INC on the following 'Table2' where [Number_Of_Customers] is aggregated on [Brand] and [Year] level

| City | Number_Of_Customers |
| --- | --- |
| Birmingham | ... |
| Bristol | ... |
| London | ... |
| Manchester | .... |
| York | .... |

where in 'Table2' I filter columns [Brand] and [Year] with multi-valued filters,
e.g. for [Brand] = "A" and [Year] = {"2019","2020"} the 75th percentile should be 2917 (I get this result from EXCEL function PERCENTILE.INC).

So far used the following formula

```
75th_Percentile = 

CALCULATE(
    PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Number_of_Customers],0.75), 
    ALL('Table1'[City])
)
```

but this doesn't work  ( see image below where I get wrong value [75th_Percentile] = 2240,25 ).

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second try:**

```
  75th_Percentile = 
 VAR a = CALCULATETABLE(ADDCOLUMNS( SUMMARIZE( Table1 , Table1[City]), "@total", CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Number_of_Customers]))), ALLSELECTED(Table1))

RETURN    PERCENTILEX.INC (a, [@total],0.75)
```

**First try:**

What happens if you remove the calculate?

```
75th_Percentile = 
    PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Number_of_Customers],0.75)
```

[image]

Comment: your formula doesn't yield the desired result  ( for [Brand] = "A" and [Year] = {"2019","2020"} I should get [75th_Percentile] = 2917 ). Thanks

Comment: When I put those values in Excel, I get 2240 at the total level...same as PBI. Values are: 2465
452
948
214
2654
2999
679
353
1566
387. Formula is =PERCENTILE.INC(L15:L24,0.75)

Comment: 2240 is the 75th percentile on the filtered rows of 'Table1'. However, I wish to calculate the percentile of the aggregated 'Table2' (see Table2 in my question). Thanks

Comment: I'll leave this as I'm clearly not understanding the requirement. I'll update my answer with what I'm seeing...

Comment: Another way to replicate my expected results are following steps  **1/** pass 'Table1' into Excel **2/** create in EXCEL a pivot table based on 'Table1' where you select columns [City] and [Number_Of_Customers] with Value Field Settings as 'Sum' **3/** calculate manually in a cell in Excel the 75th percentile of the five values of the resulting pivot table using the PERCENTILE.INC function where you filter in pivot table [Brand] = "A" and [Year] = {"2019","2020"}. Then you see that the result is 2917. Thanks

Comment: I see. I'll update my answer.

Comment: When I run your second try I get error message " Cannot find table 'Table' "

Comment: Updated. I had a debug table in there. The new formula works.